# C# Product with Name and Price using angularjs and asp .net local DB

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm new C# and asp .net student, and i have a problem with my code.
basically i made a program that you can Add a product putting a name and check the checkbox prices.
Here is the code:

**Services.cs**

```
    public partial class Services
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double ProductPreco { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddProduct(string newProduct, Boolean Mao, Boolean Pe)
    {
        double newPreco = 0;

        if (Mao)
        {
            newPreco += 15;
        }

        if (Pe)
        {
            newPreco += 17;
        }

        var db = new ecommandDBEntities();
        db.Services.Add(new Services() { ProductName = newProduct, ProductPreco = newPreco });
        db.SaveChanges();

        var products = db.Services.ToList();
        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**dbo.Services (DATABASE):**

```
    [Id]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ProductName]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[ProductPreco] MONEY    NULL,
```

My problem is: the program works well, it insert in table a name and price. But when i ADD another product, the price come to value: 0. But the name stay there correctly.

Can anyone help me please? I'm so lost because i don't understand C# and SQL yet.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you have any trigger defined on that table? specifically an `after insert trigger`

Comment: Can you show me an example? i didn't understand what i have to do. Thanks!